# Can you add a tile to a $7\times 7$ checkerboard so that it is tile-able by $5$ ominoes ($5\times1$ rectangles)?

Tags: combinatorics

Can you add a tile to a $7\times7$ checkerboard so that it is tile-able by $5$ ominoes ($5\times1$ rectangles)? If so, where must you place the extra tile? If not, explain why.

you can add a tile because you would need the checkerboard to be a multiple of $5$. and a $7\times7$ checkboard means there are $49$ squares which is not a multiple of $5$ so by adding $1$, we get 50 which is a multiple of $50$.

Now im having difficult of where to place the extra tile

Comment: Yes, but if you add a tile, as the instructions indicate, then you'll have $7 \times 7 + 1 = 50$ tiles, and that is a multiple of $5$.  It may still not be possible, but if so, you'll have to show it a different way.

Comment: @BrianTung, i totally read the question wrong, i didnt see the add part. let me fix the question then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 2 &3&4&5&1&2\\2&3&4&5&1&2&3\\
3&4&5&1&2&3&4\\ 4&5&1&2&3&4&5\\
5&1&2&3&4&5&1\\ 1&2&3&4&5&1&2\\ 2&3&4&5&1&2&3 \end{array}$$

Each $1\times 5$ tile will cover a $1$, a $2$, a $3$, a $4$, and a $5$.  Is there a tile you can add, within this numbering scheme, and get everything to work out?

Comment: Good (hint toward a) solution, but minor typo.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks.  Did I find the typo, or did I fix a different one?

Comment: Haha, no, you found the typo I saw.

Comment: It seems I cant, when I try I end up with either 3 or 4 remaining tiles in either an L or square shape.

Comment: @swandilaon:  as there are $11$ squares numbered $2$, you are stuck.

Comment: @RossMillikan I got it.